# Too many comps of type "BUFGMUX" found to fit this device. (Ethernet Design)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I'm designing an Ethernet MAC Controller for Spartan 3E FPGA. IOBs have reached 109%. I still proceeded with the generation of bitstream. I then encountered this error:

Too many comps of type "BUFGMUX" found to fit this device.
[image]
What does this mean?

(I'm pretty sure that running the Spartan 3e can run the Ethernet since there is already an IP of Ethernet lite MAC for Spartan 3e. Also, it has more pins than I have in my module. Why does it have then 109% of IOBs?) 
[image]

I also tried commenting the instantiated mac_transmit_module and mac_receive_module. It generated bitstream successfully. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your design is simply too large to fit on the target FPGA. The fact that there is similar IP suggests that your implementation is somehow less efficient or has features that the other IP does not. There is no simple, one-size-fits-all solution to this problem.

Can I suggest that in the future you don't just include screen captures as documentation? They are very hard to read and most of the image is irrelevant. If there is a particular error message you want us to see, do a copy-paste into your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you use 255 out of 232 IOBs. You have selected xs3s500e-4fg323, which indeed only has 232 user IOs, 56 of which are input-only. Maybe you selected the wrong part for synthesis?

If you are relatively sure you selected the right part, check the "IOB Properties" report ISE. There, you will get a list of all used IOBs. If that does not work (because maybe the error occurs before this is generated), you can always check the floorplanning tools with your UCF file in order to determine if some LOCs are simply wrong. Do this on a dummy design with just your UCF and the floorplanner.

Secondly, the BUFGMUX message is telling you that you use too many global clock buffers in general (or really too many muxed clocks, unlikely). When a design features many clocks, ISE has to use BUFGMUX primitives in addition to the BUFG primitives in order to route all clocks. Now, if you exceed the number of BUFGMUXs/BUFGs in your design, you will get that error.

So both errors point to either your design being too large, or a wrong part selection.

Answer (score 0):

BUFGMUXs are used to buffer signals which are used as clocks.

In most designs, especially as a beginner, you should only have one clock.  And all your processes should be of the same form, with your clock signal in the sensitivity list and an `if rising_edge(clock) then` line in there.  This is called synchronous design, and if you don't do it, all sorts of buggy results are likely to be forthcoming when you try your code out in a real chip.  Don't do it until you have enough experience.  You can tell when you have enough experience because when you think of using another clock signal you'll think "surely I can find a way of sticking to one clock signal" :)

It sounds to me like you have `if rising_edge(all sorts of different signals in different processes)` - this makes the tools produce a lot of signals it thinks are clocks, and then hang a BUFGMUX off each one of them, not only do you run out of clock routing resources very quickly, but you will get unpredictable behaviour.